# Что такое ret в данном случае? ( ret, frame = cap.read() )

Tags: python, opencv

Только начал знакомится с Python и OpenCV.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
# Capture frame-by-frame
ret, frame = cap.read()

# Our operations on the frame come here
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Display the resulting frame
cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Нашел хороший код который демонстрирует работу с камерой, но из-за плохого знания языка не понимаю что **ret** в этой строке:

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

cap.read() в ret возвращает значение, типа Boolean (True/False).
Если frame прочитан корректно: ret = True.

Comment: Спасибо, а не подскажите где можно почитать про эту фичу?

Comment: Пожалуйста. Рад был помочь.
Почитать можно тут:
http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html